# Adding more information into the azure activity log

Tags: azure, monitoring, webhooks, azure-application-insights

Is there anyway where I can configure [[image]azure](/questions/tagged/azure) to add additional resource information into the [activity-log](/questions/tagged/activity-log) that is provided via REST api? I am using [azure-insights](/questions/tagged/azure-insights) sdk.

Right now, the [activity-log](/questions/tagged/activity-log) does not contain resource size related information. The custom properties in the [webhook](/questions/tagged/webhook) alert (as metioned [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Create-Azure-Alerts-with-b938077a)) are treated like constants that are calculated only at the time of [webhook](/questions/tagged/webhook)setup.

The [activity-log](/questions/tagged/activity-log) treat resource resize event as "write" operation and won't provide details on whether it was up-size or down-size. Same case for de-allocation event as well. I am trying to add resource size information into the activity log for each event occurrence so that I can calculate the usage pattern and other metrics.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently researching on Azure Activity log, and I found zero evidence of what you are trying to achieve. I believe that it is impossible (at this point), but I really have no links to back it up.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is not possible today. Customer can not control the type of data that is logged into Activity Logs. This is controlled by the platform.